# Compress a folder with all subfolders into a .jar file

Tags: jar, sdk, compression, executable-jar

I have a directory of **files with sub-folders** and I want to **compress** it all in ***a jar file***.

Later on , I need to use it in my project and add this jar file into my library section at eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on a blank area in explorer window, go to New > Compressed (zipped) Folder. Drop whatever you want into it, and then rename the extension to *.jar. 
[source](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/387916-how-can-i-easily-create-a-jar-file-in-windows/)